# ng-click inside the ng-repeat binding all the data with ng-include

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

I want to include the html page with the help of ng-click inside the ng-repeat. 
But, it loading all the content for all ng-repeat elements.
My requirement was I want to bind(ng-include) only the clicked element.
    Please find the attachment  for your reference.

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="message in messages">
        <a ng-click="clickMe()">Clike Me</a>
        <span>{{ message.text }}---{{ message.type }}</span>
        <div ng-include="templateUrl"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    var messages = [
        { text: "Standard Message", type: "success000" },
        { text: "Success Message!", type: "success111" },
        { text: "Alert Message!", type: "alert222" },
        { text: "secondary message...", type: "secondary333" }
    ]
    $scope.name = 'shiva';
    $scope.count = 0;
    $scope.messages = messages;
    $scope.clickMe = function () {
        //   alert('clicked');
        $scope.count++;
        $scope.templateUrl = "Page.html";
    };
});
```

**page.Html**

```
<b> Included html Code.{{message.type}}---count={{count}}
```

Comment: Plese find the attached plunker for your reference.http://plnkr.co/edit/8vcbWkBhHsL191UrFcd3?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Add to `message` new property `clicked`. Set `ng-include` only when `message.clicked` is `true` using `ng-if`. And when you `click`, change state of `message.clicked` on `true`

Somthing like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
            var  messages = [
      { text: "Standard Message", type: "success0" ,clicked:false},
      {text:"Success Message!", type:"success00",clicked:false},
      {text:"Alert Message!", type : "alert2",clicked:false},
      {text:"secondary message...", type : "secondary3",clicked:false}
            ]
            $scope.name = 'shiva';
            $scope.count = 0;
            $scope.messages = messages;
            $scope.clickMe = function (message) {
             //   alert('clicked');
                $scope.count++;
                message.clicked=true;
                $scope.templateUrl = "Page.html";
            };

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">  
    <div ng-repeat="message in messages">
        <a ng-click="clickMe(message)">Clike Me</a>
        <span>{{message.text}}---{{message.type}}</span>
        <div ng-if="message.clicked" ng-include="templateUrl"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add an `id` your json data as follows:

```
var messages = [
    { id: "101", text: "Standard Message", type: "success0", clickCount: 0 },
    { id: "102", text: "Success Message!", type: "success00", clickCount: 0 },
    { id: "103", text: "Alert Message!", type: "alert2", clickCount: 0 },
    { id: "104", text: "secondary message...", type: "secondary3", clickCount: 0 }
]
```

Next you need to run a `filter` and find the item on `ng-click`

```
$scope.clickMe = function (obj) {
    $scope.messages.forEach(function (value, key) {
        if (value.id === obj.id) {
            value.isClicked = true;
            value.clickCount++;
        }
    });
    $scope.count++;
    $scope.templateUrl = "Page.html";
};
```

After that, make changes into your *Page.html*

```
<p class="info">{{ name }}--{{ message.type }}--{{ message.text }}</p>
<p class="element">
    Current Count = ({{ message.clickCount }}), Total Count = ({{ count }})
</p>
```

At last you need to make the following two HTML changes

1) Add the object in `ng-click`

```
<a ng-click="clickMe(message)">Clike Me</a>
```

2) Specify the condition on `ng-include`

```
<div ng-include="templateUrl" ng-if="message.isClicked"></div>
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pn3cdhynXJ6cbVjylSay?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for answer. But Its hiding the previous click event and binding/showing the new click event  results.My requirement was I need to show previous click result and  also current clicked event results.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have updated my Plunker. You can view the same link to see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. You are not getting my requirement.

Comment: The previous clicked result will always be one less than that of current one. What say?

Comment: Thanks. You are not getting my requirement.If user clicks, we should show particular click events result not all click result. For example user click on ClickMe2 we should show that particular click event result. Then after  again if user clicks on ClickMe1 we should show ClickMe1 event result and also don't hide previous results(ClickMe2 result). I update plunker please check